# if tags get reapeated in xml then those data has to get individually by thru using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

if suppose the same tags will be repeated but for that tag value will be different since i need to fetch separately by using xslt, if i am doing that the two tag value was getting in singleline

here is my xml:

```
<local>
<message>       
    <block4>            
        <tag>
            <name>72</name>
            <value>ALW103111102000001</value>
        </tag>          
        <tag>
            <name>70</name>
            <value>TESTING CITI BANK EFT9</value>
        </tag>
        <tag>
            <name>71A</name>
            <value>OUR</value>
        </tag>
        <tag>
            <name>72</name>
            <value>ipubby</value>
        </tag>
    </block4>       
</message>
</local>
```

here is my xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="local/message">
                 <xsl:for-each select ="block4/tag[name = '72']">
            <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
        </xsl:for-each>,<xsl:text/> 
                    <xsl:for-each select ="block4/tag[name = '72']">
            <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
     </xsl:stylesheet>
```

output required as :

**ALW103111102000001,ipubby**

Comment: I fail to see the actual question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you are asking is that you want to match all the **tag** elements with a **name** of 72, and concatenate the values on to one single line.

At the the moment, you are nesting your **xsl:for-each** statements, which result in the elements getting selected twice, and your output line is getting duplicated.

What you need to do, is simply select the first tag like so

```
<xsl:value-of select="block4/tag[name = '72'][1]/value"/>
```

And then you can get the remaining tags like so....

```
<xsl:for-each select="block4/tag[name = '72'][position() > 1]">
```

Note that it would be preferable to use **xsl:apply-templates** to match the nodes, rather than **xsl:for-each**.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="local/message"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="message">
      <xsl:value-of select="block4/tag[name = '72'][1]/value"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="block4/tag[name = '72'][position() &gt; 1]"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="tag">
      <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="value"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your given input XML, the output is as follows:

```
ALW103111102000001,ipubby
```